# Finding the locus of a point

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]
  I was thinking about the above problem .Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any point $A$ on the circle, $B$ will be any point on the circle of radius $b$ with center $A$. Since this will be true for any $A$ on the circle, the locus of $B$ will be the figure formed by a circle that rotates around a point. Therefore, I would say the right answer is C, since for any point in the region between the two cocentric circles you can find an $A$ such that $A$ is on the circle and $|AB|=b$.

Comment: This is a right picture of what is going on the plane.

Answer (score 1):

The locus of B takes every point on the circle to another, some distance $b$ from the original in a given direction. Does that help?

Comment: A is on the circumference of the circle.

Comment: On the circle means on the circumference of the circle..that is what i think from the question.No other information is given about it.